# PHP AJAX echo json data before then sleep

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have tried out couple answers here but none worked.

I have this basic honeypot script:

```
  if (!empty($_POST['starttime'])) {

        $current_time = time();
        $json = array();
        $json = reGenerateFormFields();//hold the hashed keys arays for change in the key output.

        if (($current_time - htmlentities(@$_POST['starttime'])) < 4) { // 3 is number of seconds differential
                        $return = array('hp' => true,'message' =>'אנא המתן 3 שניות בין שליחה','key' => $json['2'], 'nonce' => $json['1'],'time' => time());
              echo json_encode($return);
            sleep(7);
            die();
            
        }
}
```

I am trying to echo the json message and then sleep. But now it is first do sleep then echo the message. Any idea how to do it the good way?

Comment: "_its first do sleep then echo the message_" No, it doesn't. It may seem that way if you are viewing the output in a browser. If that is the case, flush the output after the echo statement, before the `sleep`.

Comment: Already try, didn't work, it's keep sleep then message.

Comment: What's this supposed to do `@$_POST['starttime']` ? `@` suppresses errors from functions / methods, and does nothing to variables.

Comment: How does its related to my question? its something i use and needed to suppresses errors. also you probably the one who devote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the echo'd data is just being buffered rather than sent until sleep finishes and the request completes. Try using `flush()` to force pushing the output to the client:

```
echo json_encode($return);
flush();
sleep(7);
die();
```

If this fails, you may find padding the output will help meet the server/browser's minimum length requirement to flush/display the data:

```
echo str_pad(json_encode($return),8192," ");
flush();
sleep(7);
die();
```

Comment: @Ravg If your server is using mod_gzip you'll have to disable it, as it does its own buffering.

Comment: @Ravg Added another option to try

Comment: I try disable via htaccses not working, never mind i close i will pass it on.

Comment: @Ravg Did you try the second code snipped I posted? If it's not working, try increasing the amount of padding even more.